# 2048 game implementation in Clojure

Tags: beginner, clojure, 2048

This is my first Clojure program. If you want to run it locally please check out https://github.com/achikin/game2048-clj

core.clj

```
(ns game2048.core
  (:require [nightlight.core :refer [start]])
  (:require [game2048.ui :as ui])
  (:require [lanterna.screen :as s])
  (:require [game2048.game :as g])
  (:gen-class))

(def x 1)
(def y 1)

(defn game-loop
  [scr board]
    (recur 
     scr 
     (ui/draw-board
      scr x y
      (g/game-step (s/get-key-blocking scr) board))))

(defn -main []
  (let [scr (s/get-screen) board (g/new-board)]
    (s/in-screen scr 
      (do
        (ui/draw-board scr x y board)
        (ui/draw-agenda scr x (+ y (:height g/board-size) 1) g/agenda)
        (game-loop scr board)))))
```

game.clj

```
(ns game2048.game
  (:require [game2048.board :as b]))

(def max-score 2048)

(def board-size {:width 4 :height 4})

(def agenda
  '("←↑→↓ - make move"
    "r - reset"
    "q - quit"))

(defn new-board []
  (b/add-random-tiles (b/empty-board board-size)))

(defn process-key
  "Either exit or transform board according to a key passed"
  [key board]
  (case key
    (:up :down :left :right) (b/make-move key board)
    \q (System/exit 0)
    \r (b/empty-board board-size)))

(defn check-board
  "Check for logical conditions and transform board accordingly"
  [board-before-keypress board]
  (let [board-after-rand (b/add-random-tiles board)]
    (cond
      (= board-before-keypress board) board
      (b/full? board-after-rand) (new-board)
      (b/contains-max? max-score board) (new-board)
      :else board-after-rand)))

(defn game-step
  [key board]
  (check-board board
    (process-key key board)))
```

ui.clj

```
(ns game2048.ui
 (:require [game2048.board :as b])
 (:require [lanterna.screen :as s]))

(def maxlen 5)

(defn count-digits [n] 
  (if (zero? n) 1
   (-> n Math/log10 Math/floor long inc)))

(defn repeat-str
  [n st]
  (apply str (repeat n st)))

(defn pad-number
  [length number]
  (let [n (count-digits number)
        pads (/ (- length n) 2)]
    (apply str (repeat-str pads " ") (str number) (repeat-str pads " "))))

(defn max-number
  [board]
  (apply max board))

(defn max-length
  [board]
  (+ (count-digits (max-number board)) 2))

(defn draw-row
  ([screen x y row]
   (if-not (empty? row)
      (do
       (s/put-string screen x y (pad-number maxlen (first row)))     
       (recur screen (+ x maxlen) y (rest row))))))

(defn draw-rows
  "Draw each row and update screen"
  [screen x y rows]
  (if-not (empty? rows)
    (do 
      (draw-row screen x y (first rows))
      (recur screen x (inc y) (rest rows)))
    (s/redraw screen)))

(defn draw-board
  "Break board into horizontal rows and draw them into lanterna/screen
  returns initial board for further processing"
  [screen x y board]
  (do
    (draw-rows screen x y (b/part-board :horizontal board))
    board))

(defn draw-agenda
  [scr x y [first & rest]]
  (if first
    (do
      (s/put-string scr x y first)
      (recur scr x (inc y) rest))
    (s/redraw scr)))
```

board.clj

```
(ns game2048.board
  (:require [game2048.row :as row]))

(defn get-n-zeroes
  [n]
  (repeat n 0))

(defn empty-board 
  "Board is represented as width, height and 1 dimentional list of fields
  Zero represents empty field"
  [size]
  (merge size {:data (get-n-zeroes (* (:width size) (:height size)))}))

(defn part-board
  "Partition board list into horizontal or vertical slices"
  [direction board]
  (case direction
    :horizontal (partition (:width board) (:data board))
    :vertical (partition (:height board) 
               (apply interleave 
                 (partition (:width board) (:data board))))))

(defn gather
  "Gather board from horizontal or vertical slices
back into map"
  [direction board]
  (case direction
    :horizontal {:width (-> board first count) 
                 :height (count board) 
                 :data (apply concat board)}
    :vertical {:width (count board) 
               :height (-> board first count) 
               :data (apply interleave board)}))

(defn find-indexes
  "Find all indexes of value in collection" 
  [val coll]
  (reduce-kv 
    (fn [a k v] (if (= v val) (conj a k) a))                     
    []
    coll)) 

(defn choose-index
  "Choose random value from collection"
  [indexes]
  (rand-nth indexes))

(defn choose-value 
  "2 chosen with 2/3 probability
   4 chosen with 1/3 probability"
  []
  (rand-nth '(2 2 4)))

(defn rand-replace
  "Replace one value in collection with another one chosen with index-fn"
  [index-fn oldval value-fn coll]
  (let [array (into [] coll)
        indexes (find-indexes oldval array)]
   (if (empty? indexes)
       coll
       (seq (assoc array 
              (index-fn indexes) (value-fn))))))

(defn add-random-tile
  "Replace random zero with 2 or 4 in seq"
  [board]
  (rand-replace choose-index 0 choose-value board))

(defn add-random-tiles
  "Replace random zero with 2 or 4 in board
  in case if you want to add more than one tile"
  [board]
  (assoc board :data (add-random-tile (:data board))))


(defn which-partition
  "Determine if move is horizontal or vertical"
  [direction]
  (if (contains? #{:left :right} direction)
    :horizontal
    :vertical))

"Up movement is eqivalent to left movement
and down movement equivalent to right movement"
(def dir-map 
  {:up :left 
   :down :right 
   :left :left 
   :right :right})

(defn make-move
  "Break board into either horizontal or vertical slices
perform move on each slice, and gather result back into new board"
  [direction board]
  (let [part (which-partition direction)]
    (gather part
      (map #(row/move (direction dir-map) %) (part-board part board)))))

(defn full?
  "True if there are no empty(0) fields left"
  [board]
  (not-any? #{0} (:data board)))

(defn contains-max?
  "True if one of the sells reached maximum value"
  [max-score board]
  (not (empty? (filter #(= max-score %) (:data board)))))
```

row.clj

```
(ns game2048.row)

(defmulti padd (fn [direction len coll] direction))
"Pad collections with zeroes either on the left or on the right"
(defmethod padd :left
  [direction len coll]
  (concat (repeat (- len (count coll)) 0) coll))
(defmethod padd :right
  [direction len coll]
  (concat coll (repeat (- len (count coll)) 0)))

(defmulti merger(fn [dir & args] dir))
"Check if there are equal adjustent fields and merge them
e.g. (merger :left '(1 1 2 2)) -> (2 4)"

(defmethod merger :left
  ([dir [first second & rest] newrow]
   (if first
    (if (= first second)
     (recur dir rest (cons (+ first second) newrow))
     (recur dir (cons second rest) (cons first newrow)))
    (reverse newrow)))
  ([dir row]
   (merger dir row '())))

(defmethod merger :right
  [dir row]
  (reverse (merger :left (reverse row))))

(defn remove-zeroes
  "Return collection dropping all zeroes"
  [coll]
  (filter (fn [x] (not (zero? x))) 
    coll))

(defn opposite-dir
  [dir]
  (case dir
    :left :right
    :right :left))

(defn move
  "Remove zeroes, then merge values, then pad result with zeroes
  e.g. (move :left '(1 1 0 2 2) -> (1 1 2 2) -> (2 4 0 0 0)"
  [dir row]
  (let [row-size (count row)]
    (padd (opposite-dir dir) row-size (merger dir (remove-zeroes row)))))
```

board_test.clj

```
(ns game2048.board-test
  (:use clojure.test)
  (:require [game2048.board :as b]))

(def empty-board-3-3 
  {:width 3
   :height 3
   :data '(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)})

(def empty-board-2-4 
  {:width 2
   :height 4
   :data '(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)})

(deftest empty-board
  (is (= (b/empty-board {:width 3 :height 3}) empty-board-3-3))
  (is (= (b/empty-board {:width 2 :height 4}) empty-board-2-4)))

(def part-board-2-2
  {:width 2
   :height 2
   :data '(1 1 2 2)})
(def part-board-2-2-left
  {:width 2
   :height 2
   :data '(2 0 4 0)})

(def part-board-2-2-horizontal '((1 1)(2 2)))
(def part-board-2-2-vertical '((1 2)(1 2)))

(deftest part-board
  (is (= (b/part-board :horizontal part-board-2-2) part-board-2-2-horizontal))
  (is (= (b/part-board :vertical part-board-2-2) part-board-2-2-vertical)))

(deftest gather
  (is (= (b/gather :horizontal '((1 1) (2 2))) part-board-2-2))
  (is (= (b/gather :vertical '((1 2) (1 2))) part-board-2-2)))

(defn index-fn-1
  [coll]
  1)

(defn index-fn-3
  [coll]
  3)

(defn value-fn-2
  []
  2)

(defn value-fn-4
  []
  4)
(deftest rand-replace
  (is (= (b/rand-replace index-fn-1 0 value-fn-2 '(0 0 0)) '(0 2 0)))
  (is (= (b/rand-replace index-fn-3 0 value-fn-4 '(0 0 0 0 0)) '(0 0 0 4 0))))

(def board-move
  {:width 2
   :height 2
   :data '(2 4 2 4)})
(def board-move-up
  {:width 2
   :height 2
   :data '(4 8 0 0)})

(def board-move-down
  {:width 2
   :height 2
   :data '(0 0 4 8)})

(deftest make-move
  (is (= (b/make-move :left part-board-2-2) part-board-2-2-left))
  (is (= (b/make-move :up board-move) board-move-up))
  (is (= (b/make-move :down board-move) board-move-down))
  (is (= (b/make-move :right board-move) board-move)))

(deftest full
  (is (b/full? {:width 2 :height 2 :data '(1 2 3 4)}))
  (is (not (b/full? {:width 2 :height 2 :data '(1 2 3 0)}))))

(deftest contains-max
  (is (b/contains-max? 2048 {:width 2 :height 2 :data '(1 2 2048 4)})))
```

Flowchart
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `core.clj`

> ```
> (def x 1)
> (def y 1)
> ```

1. Use more descriptive names.  These seem to be used as the origin for rendering the game, so maybe something like `x-origin` and `y-origin` would be good.
2. Add docstrings to document the meaning and purpose of each var / function
3. It might be worth-while making these dynamic vars.  Then you can render the game in a different location (e.g., if you want to render *two* games for head-to-head competition) using `bindings`.
4. You could combine the two into a single `*origin*` var.

Combining these points, you'd end up with something like:

```
(def ^:dynamic *origin*
  "Defines the origin at which to render the game"
  [1 1])
```

## `game.clj`

> ```
> (def agenda
>   '("←↑→↓ - make move"
>     "r - reset"
>     "q - quit"))
> ```

I like the way you take a data-centric approach here.  It's a good pattern.

> ```
> (defn process-key
>   "Either exit or transform board according to a key passed"
>   [key board]
>   (case key
>     (:up :down :left :right) (b/make-move key board)
>     \q (System/exit 0)
>     \r (b/empty-board board-size)))
> ```

1. You have the keys hard-coded to their actions.  You could decouple this by using a data-centric approach (similar to `agenda`).
2. You don't have a clause in your `case`, so this code will throw an exception if any other key is pressed.
3. Ending the game by calling `System/exit` limits what you can do afterwards.  For example, you can't go back to a menu of games.  Avoid `System/exit` unless it is absolutely necessary.  One way to avoid it in this case would be to return `nil`.  Then have your main loop terminate if a `nil` is encountered.

Using a data-centric approach, I would do something like this:

```
(def ^:dynamic *actions*
  "Maps keys to action fns.  Each action is a function that takes a board state and returns a new board state."
  {:up    b/move-up
   :down  b/move-down
   :left  b/move-left
   :right b/move-right
   \q     (constantly nil)
   \r     (fn [board]
            (b/empty-board board-size))})
```

Then `process-key` can be defined as:

```
(defn process-key
  "Either exit or transform board according to a key passed"
  ([key board]
    (let [action (get *actions* key identity)]
      (action board))))
```

`identity` is used as the default to provide an effective no-op when the key can't be mapped.

## `board.clj`

All the functions that manipulate board state deal directly with the internal representation of the board -- there's no abstraction.  You should consider defining a protocol to define an interface for dealing with boards.  There are many approaches.  Here's one option:

```
(defprotocol IBoard
  (rows [board] [board data])
  (columns [board] [board data])
```

Then use `deftype` to provide an implementation.

Now, we can define the `move-` functions like:

```
(defn move-up [board]
  (columns board (map compress (columns board))))

(defn move-down [board]
  (columns board (map reverse (map compress (map reverse (columns board))))))
```

Though it would be more idiomatic to use `->>`:

```
(defn move-left [board]
  (->> (rows board)   ;; Obtain row-centric view of the board
       (map compress) ;; "Compress" each row
       (rows board))) ;; Construct new board from compressed rows

(defn move-right [board]
  (->> (rows board)   ;;
       (map reverse)  ;; Reverse rows, so compression happens in correct order
       (map compress) ;; "Compress" each row
       (map reverse)  ;; Reverse rows back to original order
       (rows board))) ;; Construct new board from compressed rows
```

If desired, you could refactor these to take advantage of the shared structure.

`compress` takes a sequence and replaces consecutive elements with a single element of their sum.  For the above functions to work, the result of `compress` must have the same length as its input (i.e., padded with `0`s).  Otherwise, you'll have to handle padding elsewhere.

I believe this design would allow you to get rid of `row.clj`.

## `ui.clj`

> ```
> (def maxlen 5)
> ```

I think you should avoid a hard limit here.  At the very least, make `maxlen` dynamic.  But even better, calculate it dynamically via `max-length` (which you currently don't use, BTW).  If you do this, you might want to have a `minlen`, to avoid the cell size changing too often.

> ```
> (defn count-digits [n] 
>   (if (zero? n) 1
>    (-> n Math/log10 Math/floor long inc)))
> ```

This is *way* too complicated.  Just convert the number to a string and count the number of characters in the string:

```
(defn count-digits [n]
  (count (str n)))
```

Alternatively, use `String`'s `length` property:

```
(defn count-digits [n]
  (. (str n) length))
```

> ```
> (defn draw-row
>   ([screen x y row]
>    (if-not (empty? row)
>       (do
>        (s/put-string screen x y (pad-number maxlen (first row)))     
>        (recur screen (+ x maxlen) y (rest row))))))
> ```

Avoid using `recur` if there's an alternative that fits well.  In this case, I would use `doseq`:

```
(defn draw-row
  ([screen x y row]
    (doseq [[i n] (zip (range) row)]
      (let [x' (+ x (* i maxlen))
            n' (pad-number maxlen n)]
        s/put-string screen x' y n'))))
```

The same applies for `draw-rows`.

Also, you're calling `s/redraw` in `draw-rows`.  I think it would make more sense to call it from `draw-board`.  But really, redrawing the screen is arguably a separate concern from rendering the board.  So it might be best to do the redraw at a higher level, such as the main loop.